# Outlook Calendar - Locations set by Add-in is cleared on save

Tags: office-js

Our Outlook add-in, as part of its process, sets the location field to a link.
This all works fine, no errors or warnings. However, recently in the web client, after setting the location in this way, once the appointment is saved and closed, the location is removed. If you're watching the item on the calendar, you can actually see it disappear within a couple seconds.

Manually typed or pasted locations do not have this problem, nor does the native Outlook client. Using the saveAsync method before save and close does not prevent the location from being deleted either.

This does not appear to be isolated to our add-in, a cursory test of the Starbucks add-in (available in the store) showed the same behaviour - location cleared on save, in the web client.

Is there a work-around for this, or is it to be expected behaviour moving forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We apologize for any frustration or inconvenience we have caused with this issue. Please be patient as we work to fix this issue as quickly as we can.

Currently, we do not have a workaround.

Comment: We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build <16.00.2149.000> or later. Depending on the release channel, getting an update build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.

Comment: How will we know when Outlook Web client has been fixed, I'm not sure how to tell what build version is available there.

Comment: Hi Outlook Team. Could you add a public tracking link to your question please, and also an update on the fix status. I assume some six years on, the bug is now resolved.